# How to retrive sharepoint list items programatically using app registration client id and secret?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get sharepoint list items from api calls using a app registration to authenticate.
My app registration already have the permission sites.selected at application level (not delegate).
I am able to generate the token, but when I try to retrive the items, i got a forbidden.
What could I be missing here?

```
def __init__(self, tenantId, clientId, clientSecret):
    self.tenant_id = tenantId
    self.client_id = clientId
    self.client_secret = clientSecret
    self.resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  # Microsoft Graph API endpoint
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{self.tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': self.client_id,
        'client_secret': self.client_secret,
        'scope': self.resource
    }
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    self.token = json_data['access_token']


def get_sharepoint_list_content(self, site, listname, **kwargs):
    filter_query = kwargs.get('filter_query', '')
    columns = kwargs.get('columns', 'id')
    top = kwargs.get('top', '')

    url = f"{site}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{listname}')/items?$select={columns}&$filter={filter_query}&$top={top}"
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token}'
    }

    list_items = []
    while url:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        lista = json.loads(response.text)
        list_items.extend(lista.get('value', []))
        url = lista.get('@odata.nextLink', '')

    return list_items
```

Comment: I presume you also took the steps required to grant access to the specific SPO site? I would check that, I had more trouble than I expected figuring that part of this out.

Comment: This! Can you link here any documentation on giving the SPO site? all the documentation that I followed skipped this part.

Comment: Posted as an answer. I ran into this exact thing with writing files, list items should not be different.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different approaches as far as granting permissions to specific sites.

1. https://ashiqf.com/2021/03/15/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-sharepoint-sites-selected-application-permission-in-a-azure-ad-application-for-more-granular-control/ - using 2 different apps, one with full control, granting access to the one with sites.selected - useful as it prevents having to deal with SPO permissions.
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.sites/new-mgsitepermission?view=graph-powershell-1.0 - the problem here is that the identity doing this needs enough access to the site. Site collection admin membership works, granted using Set-SPOUser, do note that those SPO management commands only work on Windows PowerShell.
3. https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html - another option if the Graph API PowerShell is not desirable for some reason.